# Excel Found Unreadable Content Error

Tags: excel

I have been searching on the internet this error about excel.

"Excel found unreadable content in filename.xls. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes."

When I go to Microsoft Support website, I saw this solution

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929766/en-us

In this page it says "**To resolve this issue, remove the expressions from all Current Time Member and weight on the KPI properties.**" I did not understand what to do exactly. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click yes, save under a new filename, and check the contents match what you expect. If you're able to restore using "Restore previous versions" (right click on the file in explorer) then that's an option as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I exactly did what you said, It says There are no previous versions available.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I wanted to say that. There are lots of ways which you can see this error. Firstly, your computer's clock. you should set it to your terratory. Secondly the Excel version. You should use a formal instance of Microsoft Excel. If you do not want to deal with Microsoft, LibreOffice is free and full of good features. You should try that.